# Como mockear el Postgres en WebFlux

Tags: java, postgresql, junit, mockito

Tengo problemas al mockear un test que utiliza el postgres, si le pongo datos ficticios a la cadena de conexion del postgres me sale error al momento de compilar. Adjunto estructura y build.

```
spring:
 datasource:
   driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
    hikari:
      jdbc-url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/example?currentSchema=public
      username: usuario
      password: password
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
2023-05-29 09:47:37.357 ERROR 8880 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication                   : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/sql/init/DataSourceInitializationConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [com/ingrid/ms/aplicacion/config/DataSourceConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [com/ingrid/ms/aplicacion/config/DataSourceConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "usuario"
```

El lenguaje usado es Java y test JUnit y Mockito

Saben de que otra manera puedo mockear?

Comment: Por que no intentas ponerle una base [tag:h2] para las pruebas?

Comment: Mock no implica que hagas mock de ese recurso también? Pues, como pa que una prueba unitaria sea de verdad unitaria y no de integración. Igual, ese error dice que las credenciales son erradas o que en el pg_hba.conf el método de autenticación no permite usar credenciales (debe tener trust o peer o algo así y toca cambiarlo)

Comment: @RuslanLópez por favor no se si contarás con un ejemplo de h2?

Gracias.

Comment: @Alfabravo justamente la idea del mock es que no dependas de la conexion de la BD y que funcionen las pruebas unitarias sin necesidad de estar conectado a la BD:

Comment: Por eso, la respuesta que te dan a la pregunta indica exactamente eso. No estás haciendo mock del recurso de BD y te falla la conexión porque seguro el contexto de la prueba no tiene el datasource instanciado. Revisa la respuesta de Gastón :)

Comment: @ProgrammerGirl por eso te puse la liga a la etiqueta para que busques los ejemplos en el sitio

Comment: Gracias a Gastón Schabas ya lo pude resolver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay distintos tipos de test automatizados que se pueden realizar para validar diferentes cosas del software que se está construyendo. El artículo [Pruebas de software](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pruebas_de_software) detalla bastante sobre ellos.

Ahora bien, yendo a tu pregunta, no queda claro si lo que querés es validar una lógica de negocio indistintamente de la base de datos que uses o si lo que querés es cerciorarte que tu código se comunica de forma correcta con dicha base. Para el primer caso, serían **pruebas unitarias**, para el segundo **prubas de integración**.

---

### Pruebas unitarias

Necesitarías configurar mocks que simulen la comunicación con la base de datos y devuelvan distintos resultados según el caso que estés tratando de probar. Se suelen poner toda la lógica de comunicación con la base dentro de objetos que son los cuáles vas usar mocks en vez de instancias reales. Ejemplo:

```java
MiClaseDB miClaseDBMock = mock(MiClaseDB.class);
when(miClaseDBMock.add(param1, param2, ..., paramN).thenReturn(miResultadoEsperado);
MiClaseLogica miClaseNegocio = new MiClaseLogica(miClaseDBMock);
Resultado resultado = miClaseNegocio.metodoConLogicaQueLlamaDB(param1, param2, ..., paramN);
assert(resultado, valorEsperado);
```

---

### Pruebas De Integración

Para este caso, vas a necesitar que durante la ejecución del test, haya una instancia de base de datos operativa. Lo recomendable es siempre partir de una base de datos vacía y ejecutar los scripts necesarios para crear la tablas, índices y datos iniciales necesarios para poder realizar la prueba deseada. Esto último se puede automatizar mediante [schema migration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schema_migration) y existen herramientas como [liquibase](https://www.liquibase.org/), [flyway](https://flywaydb.org/). Hay varias formas de tener funcionando una base durante la ejecución de tests:

- base de datos instalada: no es para nada la mejor opción. si tenés tests que corren en paralelo podrían generarse inconsistencias, deadlocks, etc.
- [base de datos en memoria](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_de_datos_en_memoria): es una buena opción. No necesitás de ninguna herramienta extra, claro que al correr en memoria, si trabajás con volúmenes grandes o cosas muy complejas podrías quedar limitado. Tenés opciones como [H2](https://www.h2database.com/html/main.html), [HSQLDB](https://hsqldb.org/), [Derby](https://db.apache.org/derby/), etc. Las bases de datos que acabo de listar, pueden ser consumidas a través de JDBC. Por lo que es cuestión de configurar correctamente el driver que necesitás usar durante la etapa de test. Sin embargo, al no ser exactamente el mismo motor que estás usando, podrías tener alguna discrepancia a la hora de querer validar algo muy particular y específico. Por lo que otra posible opción, podría ser usar [embedded postgre](https://github.com/zonkyio/embedded-postgres) ya que dices estar usando postgre
- bases de datos efímeras dentro de [contenedores de software](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtualizaci%C3%B3n_a_nivel_de_sistema_operativo): esta opción es la que hace que tu test se vuelva lo más cercano a tu sistema funcionando en un ambiente productivo, ya que estarías utilizando una base de datos casi real. Tendrías que tener en consideración que vas a requerir tener instalado algún sistema de contenedores como [docker](https://www.docker.com/), lo que puede terminar en un consumo mayor de recursos debido a cada contenedor que vayas a generar. Una herramienta muy buena para poder realizar esto es [testcontainers](https://www.testcontainers.org/)

Comment: Gastón Schabas muchas gracias ya lo pude mockear con H2.

Comment: Muchas de nada. Si con esta respuesta fue suficiente, por favor marcala como aceptada para que quede registrada como resulta tu pregunta. Saludos